# How can I use string interpolation to sequentially name instances of an object?

Tags: ruby, class, variables, instance-variables, string-interpolation

I have a class called `Team`. I am trying to create many instances of it and call them `team1`, `team2`, etc. I am trying something like

```
for x in (1..20)
  instancename="team#{x}"
  instancename=Team.new
end
```

I am getting the memory address of the string like `"Team:0x007f949b01d3f8"`. I assume I have to use `instance_variable_set`, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the syntax.

Comment: Normally this smell indicates you should be using an Array or a Hash. `@instances = {}; (1..20).each { |i| @instances[i] = Team.new }`

Comment: first google hit: http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set

Comment: I know, that's how I came up with the idea of using it, but I can't grok how to do it, hence the downvoted question. Gareth's solution does work, but then I have an array of instances, rather than just having the instances by themselves.

Comment: This seems like an X/Y problem. What do you plan to *do* with the instances? Why do you need to pre-generate named instances instead of working with a collection object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can do what you want with [Kernel#eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) or [Object#instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set). You can also generate collections directly. If your needs are much more complex, then you may want to think about alternative data structures.

### Using Eval

You are partly on the right track in that you need to define the variables in the current scope. While there are a number of ways to do this, the following will work:

```
Team = Struct.new :foo
for x in (1..20) do
  eval "\@team#{x} = Team.new"
end
```

This creates your instance variables:

```
@team20
#=> #<struct Team foo=nil>
```

using interpolation.

### Interpolation Without Eval

There are alternatives to [Kernel#eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval), of course, like [Object#instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set). Consider this example:

```
Team = Struct.new :foo
(1..20).each { |i| instance_variable_set "@team#{i}", Team.new }
```

I can't really see how it makes much difference in your particular case, but this allows you to avoid #eval while still doing interpolation of the variable name.

### Use a Collection

Since I can't imagine how you would use this as anything other than a collection anyway, you might as well just create a collection in the first place. For example:

```
Team = Struct.new :team_id
teams = (1..20).map { |i| Team.new i }
teams[9]
#=> #<struct Team team_id=10>
```

You can even find teams in your collection by some value, if you prefer. For example:

```
teams.select { |t| t.team_id == 10 }
#=> [#<struct Team team_id=10>]
```

None of this requires a unique variable name. You can use array position or object attributes instead, if you really need to distinguish them.

Comment: It should be noted that `eval` should be avoided whenever possible, as it can be in this case.